# Is there a way to make the Honeycomb actionbar not extend all the way across the screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a two panel layout using fragments. The left panel is 50dp wide and the right panel fills the rest of the screen. I don't want the actionbar to extend over the left fragment, just the right fragment. I haven't found anything in the documentation to indicate that this is possible, but I was wondering if anyone else has successfully managed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible. You can style the action bar, and you can make the whole bar go away, but you cannot have half a bar.

The closest you could get would be to make the whole bar go away, then implement your own action bar, but it will be tough to match the Android UI look and functionality exactly, and so I don't really recommend going down this route.

Comment: That's what I figured based on the documentation I've read. Just wanted to see if there was something out there I missed.